# How to add Youtube API in application using Firebase in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, youtube

I've been researching around the internet and i didn't found too many things about **YouTube API + Firebase**, so here's my question. I am using **Android Studio with Firebase** as a database and want to implement **Youtube API** with it, what I want is that I enter the URL of video in Firebase Database and it should make the video available in my application. I have successfully achieved this with images and text but do not know how to make it work with video, please help me.

**My firebase adapter class:**

```
public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    View mView;

    public PostViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        mView=itemView;

    }
    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        TextView post_title=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        post_title.setText(title);
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc)
    {
        TextView post_desc=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
        post_desc.setText(desc);
    }
    public void setImage(Context ctx, String image)
    {
        ImageView post_image=(ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
    }
    public void setYoutube(final Context ctx, final String youtube){
        final YouTubePlayer youPlay = (YouTubePlayer)mView.findViewById(R.id.youtubePlay);
        youPlay.with(ctx).loadVideo(youtube);
    }
}
```

**My target activity class**

```
    mYouTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubePlay);
    btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    YouTubePlayerView.initialize("YOUR API KEY",
           mOnInitialazedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                    YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {


                    youTubePlayer.loadVideo("youtube");
                }
                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                    YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                }
            });


}
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Comment: It's just showing a specific video, but I want to retrieve from firebase different videos not just one. This code above has a bug, I don't know why but, my video plays one sec. then stop.